# Conic sections ( coordinates of the point of intersection of tangents with the curve )

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I was told by my math teacher that equation of a pair of tangents drawn from the point is $T^2=SS_1$

This gives a second degree equation in $X$ and $Y$, which represents a pair of straight lines passing through the point from which tangent is drawn to the curve.

Is there any way I can find the coordinates of the point of intersections of the two tangents with the curve? I am very much interested in understanding conic sections.
Thank you for your help
[image: Problem]

Comment: No computations are needed to answer: just draw a sketch of ellipse, point and tangents. You'll see at once which is the correct choice.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca True but he also seems interested in the actual process of finding it.

Comment: In M2 `R=QQ[x,y]`
`I=ideal(x^2/9+y^2/4-1,(3*x/9+4*y/4-1)^2-(x^2/9+y^2/4-1)*(3^2/9+4^2/4-1))`
`primaryDecomposition I -- {ideal(x-3,y^2), ideal(x-2*y+5,25*y^2-80*y+64)}`

Comment: @Caedmon . Is there any way in which I can solve these type of questions in 30 seconds. (This question is from the IITJEE 2010 PAPER  WHERE WE ARE ASKED TO SOLVE 150 Hard problems in 6 hours ).

Comment: @Integer I think I would just do what Intelligenti pauca suggested. You can quickly draw the ellipse (you know it stretches 6 wide on the x-axis and 4 on the y-axis), then just plot the intersection and points. It should be clear what the answer is. Looking at the points $(3, 0)$ and $(0, 2)$ for example would be clear they meet nowhere near the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is definitely possible. This isn't the problem shown in the image, but I'll show you how to find the intersection point of $2$ tangent lines from the surface of an ellipse. We have out ellipse from the image, and let's pick $2$ points on the ellipse to use: $(1, \sqrt{32/9})$ and $(-\sqrt{135/16}, 0.5)$  First, we need to find the equations of the tangent lines we already have points, so all we need is the slopes. We can find the slopes by taking the derivative of the ellipse and solving for $\frac{dy}{dx}$:

$$\frac{x^2}{9} + \frac{y^2}{4} = 1$$
$$\frac{2x}{9} + \frac{2y\frac{dy}{dx}}{4} = 0$$
$$\frac{8x}{18} = -y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{-8x}{18y} = \frac{dy}{dx}$$

Now plug in our two points and we get a slope of $-0.2357$ and $2.582$ respectively. Now we make our two lines in point slope form and solve for $y$:

$y = -0.2357(x-1) + \sqrt{32/9}$

$y = 2.582(x+\sqrt{135/16}) + 0.5$

Then we can expand and equate the two equations to find the $x$ value for where they meet:

$2.582x + 8 = -0.2357x + 2.1213$

$x=\frac{-5.8787}{2.8177} = -2.0863$

Now plug that into one of out two tangent lines and we get an $y$ value of $2.6132$. So our two tangent lines on the ellipse intersect at a point of $(-2.0863, 2.6132)$. Here's a [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/giwitadrvi) where you can see the results. I sure hope you enjoy this because it took a while to write haha.

Comment: I understood it ! Thank you